# Resources for application pool

Tags: iis, application-pool

I have 2 websites on same IIS pointing to the same codebase as they are white label site.
Now should I create app pool for each website or should I use the same app pool for both?

I am concerned of resources on that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two websites and the same codebase, you might as well run them inside of the same Application Pool, as code changes are already a risk.

Now, if one has a potential of having a lot more traffic than another, then you might want to do separate ones to set different resource limits for each website.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to control resources like memory and cpu as well as bandwidth, you will need to have a resource pool for each site. Not sure what you mean by same codebase, each resource pool runs in its own process so be careful about sharing resources across sites.